# Exception Unhandled Error Scanning an Image with OpenCV Using .at() in c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to scan a grey scale image and determine the values of each pixel in that image using OpenCV. I am implementing a double for loop to iterate through each column row by row. I am then trying to read the pixel value at each iteration using OpenCV's function .at(). Below is my current code.

```
unsigned int column;
unsigned int row;
int pixel_value;
int img_height = image.rows;
int img_width = image.cols;

for (row = 0; row <= img_height; row++)
{
    for (column = 0; column <= img_width; column++)
    }
        pixel_value = grey_image.at<uchar>(row, column);
    }
}
```

When I run this code I get this error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFFD9D9A388 in A2V2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000EB54EFEFD0.

This error occurs at line 1107 in OpenCV's *mat.inl.hpp* file. During debugging I have stepped through the code and figured out that the inner for loop runs through completely. But after this happens once and `row` is incremented when the outer for loop runs once more is when the exception occurs.

I have tried looking up the documentation for the function `.at` but I could not see anything I am doing wrong. I also tried looking up other ways to do this such as using `MatIterator_` and a double for loop configuration with pointers (I am not confident with pointers, I need to practice them, and apparently if you use pointers you have to do more checking to make sure you are passing through the right amount of *uchar* fields and skipping gaps???, what does this mean?), from this https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html tutorial. I tried looking up documentation on these too, but I am still confused as to how they work.

I will appreciate any help, thank you for your time.

Comment: Use `<` instead of `<=`.  If you had an image of height 1 then the only valid index is 0.  Same for width.

Comment: @ Richard Critten. Thank you very much for your reply! Yes this was the problem. I am not sure why this caused it to fail but I am just glad it is working haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace <= with < since arrays start in 0, if that doesn't work, then
it seems that:

```
int img_height = image.rows;
int img_width = image.cols;
```

doesn't have the same dimensions as

```
grey_image
```

so try changing that up:

```
int img_height = grey_image.rows;
int img_width = grey_image.cols;
```

Comment: @ petacreepers23 Thank you very much for your reply! So the issue was with using `<=` instead of `<`. But I am embarrassed that I missed the fact that I was finding the dimensions of `image` and not `grey_image`. They do have the same dimensions but I was asking for trouble haha. Anyway thanks again!